econometric model to explain education impact to economic Growth
I'm working on a paper which trying to analyse the impact of education on economic growth, how to develop an econometric model to explain relationship between education and economy ?

Have you tried looking at the vast existing literature on the relationship between education (or human capital more generally) and economic output/growth?

Existing literature which I've consulted did not take into account the quality of education such as Student's score in international performance tests (TIMSS, PIRLS, PISA ...), models suggested use only quantitative parameters (average years of schooling, enrollment rates, education expenditure).
